# Initial Algebra example

Tags: semantics, formal-methods

If the definition of Initial Algebra is:

"An object is initial if there exists a unique morphism from the object to every
object in the category"

Why do we need such object, and could any one give an example ?

Comment: The quote only define "initial" not "initial algebra".

Comment: Algebra is pair of (S,F) where S is a set and F is the functions on this set

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An [initial algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_algebra) is an initial object in the category of [$F$-algebras](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-algebra) for a given endofunctor $F : \mathcal{C} \rightarrow \mathcal{C}$.

This construction is widely used to gives semantics to data-structures in (functional) programming languages. Intuitively, the functor $F$ captures the "shape" of the data-structure (e.g., $F(X) = 1 + A \times X$, with $A$ a fixed set for instance).

The underlying set $\mu F$ of the initial algebra 
$\langle \mu F, \alpha \rangle$ intuitively captures the set of syntactic expressions you can build by induction on the shape functor (e.g., for the previous functor with $A = \{a,b \}$, $\mu F = \{(1), (a,1), (b,1), (a,a,1), (a,b,1) \ldots \}$ is the set of finite lists of $A$-elements).

The initiality is the key property to construct inductive function (see [catamorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catamorphism)). Some excellent references on this topic:

- [Lectures on Semantics: The initial algebra and final coalgebra perspectives](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.46.6839)
- [A Tutorial on (Co)Algebras and (Co)Induction](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.37.1418)

Comment: What are $1$, $+$, an $\times$ notations in F(X) definition above?

Comment: terminal object, coproduct and product (respectively) in C